# Is that possible to implement [stmt]+ in yacc?

Tags: yacc, lex

I have a homework from school is to make a compiler in yacc

and the question is  :

```
PROGRAM ::= STMT+
STMT ::= EXP | PRINT-STMT
.......
```

I try to implement STMT+ like this :

```
Program : STMT_PLUS {  printf( "Program !\n" );} 
         ;
  

STMT_PLUS : STMT STMT_PLUS {}
          | ;

STMT : STMT  {}
     | EXP {}
     | PRINT_STMT {}
     |
      ;
```

The input will be multiple line .

Will it work? if it wrong , how should I edit my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use left recursion but it depends on what you are going to do in the actions. It's certainly  one of the ways of creating a grammar for `STMT*`. But it's not `STMT+`, because it evidently accepts the empty sentence.

`STMT+` would be one of:

```
STMT_PLUS: STMT
         | STMT_PLUS STMT
```

or

```
STMT_PLUS: STMT
         | STMT STMT_PLUS
```

If your goal is to build a syntax tree of some kind, either will work but the right recursion probably expresses the semantics better. If your goal is to build a line-by-line interpreter, you definitely want the left recursion; otherwise, the evaluation order will be unexpected.

If you want to **learn** how all this works, **experiment**. Try different options and see how they work.